# Ms Access 2010 FE application run via bat file BUT lock file *.laccdb remains open

Tags: batch-file, ms-access, vba

First off I seached for this topic on previous questions and on the web but cannot find any that is giving or suggesting me the solution.
I'm NOT new to access and this really drives me crazy.

I have an Access 2010 frontend accdb file that is used as below:

1. The FE Analyzer.accdb is located in the Company Server#1 in a shared folder
2. On the Company Server#2 a .bat file was created that is scheduled to run every night, and the .bat lauches the Access FE file with Access Runtime (no full MS access on the server) with the usual command:
   `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "\\192.168.1.5\SharedFolder\Analyzer.accdb`

   "C:" drive above is the one of CompanyServer#2, the IP address 192.168.1.5 is the Server#1.
3. When the access file is run, a startup form opens, in the Load event of the form, a subroutine is called that does a bunch of calculations  and writes into sql server. After calling the main subroutine, Access application is closed, like this:

   ```
   Private Sub Form_Load()
       Call Init
       Application.Quit 
   End Sub
   ```
4. The schedule works perfectly every night, the Access file accdb does what it's expected to, no MSACCESS.EXE remains in the task manager - ok so far, BUT the *.laccdb lock file remains in the shared folder!
5. When, from my client PC I access the shared folder, I can manually delete the lock file without any problems.
6. As a work-around, in the .BAT file I had written a first line that removes the lock file before running the .accdb file again.
7. BUT now that's annoying again, because I set auto-compact on close, and it doesn't work, I think because the Access accdb file is not closed properly - the lock file still there being some evidence.
8. If I run the Access frontend file that is in the shared folder (just double click it and let the startup form run the main subroutine) from my client PC it works and no lock file remains.
9. If I run the .BAT file that is on the Server#2 from my client PC, also everything runs and no lock file remains.

Any clue?

Comment: Try to run the bat file on SERVER#2 manually without task scheduler and see if that does make a difference. Or you may try to install full version ACCESS and test again, or install ACCESS RUNTIME on another pc and test from there, or... Anyway it sounds like a troubleshooting task rather than programming.

Comment: What happens on adding to batch file above the command line running MS Access the line `pushd "\\192.168.1.5\SharedFolder"`, modify the MS Access command line to `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" Analyzer.accdb` and next insert one more command line with just the command `popd`?

Comment: Thanks sst and Mofi. I've basically already tried sst's suggestions, but installing the full ACCESS which I cannot do.
Mofi's try sounds interesting, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: When you run the application as a scheduled task, you are likely running under a different user or some user on the server that does not have delete rights to the folder. So everything works when you manually run the bat file, but when scheduled, your user rights are likely different (check the box options in the scheduler - might want to check option for admin rights, and there are also a few other "user" options to check/try